# WARNING: Unsupported device 'ACTIVEX' for EXCEL destination. Using device 'ACTXIMG'

Tags: excel, sas, ods, proc-report

I am getting 'ACTIVEX' warning message in SAS while running below code, I  ignored that warning in log when i was running in SAS EG but when i run code through SAS Console (Scheduler) program is failing because of below error.
"ERROR: The width of Status is not between 1 and 132. Adjust the column width or line size."

I had researched in google and as per reference based on that i have added ODS LISTING CLOSE; and ODS LISTING; Still I am facing the same error.

```
    ODS LISTING CLOSE;
%let OUTFILE= \\Bigdata\Vikas\Myquery\REPORT_&RUN_DATE..xlsx;
ODS EXCEL FILE="&OUTFILE" OPTIONS(SHEET_NAME = "REPORT_&REPORTID");
PROC REPORT DATA=WORK.FINAL_OUTPUT
STYLE(HEADER) = {BORDERCOLOR = BLACK FONT_FACE = 'CALIBRI' FONT_SIZE = 9.5PT JUST = CENTER CELLHEIGHT=.30IN BACKGROUND=#EAEAAD FOREGROUND=BLACK}
STYLE(COLUMN) = {BORDERCOLOR = BLACK FONT_FACE = 'CALIBRI' FONT_SIZE = 9.2PT JUST = CENTER CELLHEIGHT=.30IN BACKGROUND=#FFFFFF FOREGROUND=BLACK};
RUN;
ODS EXCEL CLOSE;
ODS LISTING;
```

I don't want to see ACTIVEX warnings in the log

Comment: Is ODS HTML active?

Answer (score 1):

Add `goptions device=actximg;` before running your code.